# How to use limit-derivative relationship for this specific case?

Tags: derivatives, functional-equations

Knowing that $f$ is such that $\ f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) + xy,$

$lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} = 2.$

How can we find the value of $f'(1)$ using informations that is given.

Comment: You didn't mention what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you agree the transformations done on your text where the first line looked like a question ?

Comment: No, JeanMarie has broken the question.

Comment: Please, show us what you have done.

Comment: I have not done anything. I just wrote the whole question.

Comment: You say I have "broken" your question: it was not at all my intention. I have interpreted as I could in order for it to be mathematically intelligible.

Comment: First time i wrote the question, there was no thing that i added externally. Every statement came from question.

Comment: The initial form of your question was:                                                    I have differentiation problem from my question book. The question is:$$f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) + xy,$$ $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)}{h} = 2,$$ $$f'(1)=?$$ Do you mean that the functional equation is a **question** ? It looks not so...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48428/discussion-between-abdullah-uyu-and-jeanmarie).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your first equality

$$\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=\frac{f(y)}{y}+x$$

Take the limit for $y\to 0$.

Comment: This is a nice approach to this question. Thanks, i got the idea.